# Set Property based another property

Tags: c#, properties

If there is array of users, then SuperUserCount should be sum of user's count else it should has its own value

```
 class MyUser
 {
 public int SuperUserCount { get; set; }

 private User[] users;
 public User[] Users
 {
  get { return users;}
  set
   {
    users= value;
    if(value!=null)
     {
      SuperUserCount  = value.Sum(user => user.count);
     }
   }
 }
 }
```

I wrote the above code to get the Sum of user's count. **Not yet tested**

But how do I ensure the SuperUserCount own value do not override the SuperUserCount value set inside Users `get{}` or vice versa, when `MyUser` object is populated

Comment: _"...how do I ensure the SuperUserCount own value do not override...": just do not save value into SuperUserCount. Change it backing field to int? and its getter may directly calculate value if it's null (assuming performance aren't an issue). Vice versa? Well, define what should happen if you have Users and you set SuperUserCount...

Comment: Just *what* are you asking? You have a public setter but don't want the property to be written? If you want to set an initial value but overwrite it later and then prevent overwriting, just, add a flag. I'd reconsider this design though - it's obvious the class is trying to do two things at once

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti  the public propery should be written only when Users is null

Comment: So write body of your setter. `int SuperUserCount { get { return Users != null ? Users.Sum(x => x.count) : _superUserCount; } set { if (Users != null) throw new InvalidOperationException(); _superUserCount = value; } }`. In your `Users` setter you may also check if `SuperUserCount` property has been set before `Users` (to simply overwrite original value or to throw an exception if it's not allowed). Of course in `Users` you directly set `_superUserCount` instead of `SuperUserCount` (sorry for bad code formatting inside comment).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Will it have any impact on performance?

Comment: Yes because it'll recount each time you read `SuperUserCount`. If it's an issue then change `SuperUserCount` getter to `get { return _superUserCount; }`, its setter stays unchanged. `Users` setter will simply write `_superUserCount` without checks, always overwriting existing value (unless you want to introduce a flag or make `_superUserCount` nullable). If you go with a nullable type `int?` then you may also postpone `.Sum()` until required.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks! Can you please post it as answer so I will accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You could make the setter private, preventing it from being overridden.

```
public int SuperUserCount { get; private set; }
```

If you need to set different values for `MyUser` objects that have `null` users, then add a method specifically for that purpose.

```
public Boolean RequestOverrideSuperUserCount(int count)
{
    Boolean overrideAllowed = (null == users);
    if(overrideAllowed)
        SuperUserCount = count;
    return overrideAllowed;
}
```